# Dropped connection during multiplayer game

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan, gaming

My wife and I are trying to play an RTS PC game together. At first we played multiplayer, connecting to an external server to play our matches, but we experienced frequent issues where we would be disconnected from each other's game. After a ~10 second freeze, we'd disappear from each other's respective games and could continue playing against the AI enemies alone.

Here is a list of what I've tried, none of which helped:

- We live in an apartment complex, so I configured my router to *only* use the 5 GHz band, and I used a network analyzer to pick the channel with the least traffic. We have the channel all to ourselves and we sit within 3 meters of the router with a direct line-of-sight on both computers.
- We started playing over LAN.
- When playing over LAN, I disconnected the router from the modem to completely remove the modem and ISP from the equation.

Unfortunately I don't remember the model of my router off the top of my head, but it's a Linksys dual band. I have noticed that I'll get occasionally kicked off the internet briefly while browsing the web. My computer has top-of-the-line specs as of 2 years ago, so it's almost certainly not a performance issue on my end. The router is only 2 years old as well.

My wife's computer is getting up there in years, and I noticed that Chrome was being an exceptional memory hog last night after we were kicked off (we're talking ~4 GB here, out of her 6 total)... could we simply be running out of RAM on her end? This game was made in the early 2000s so it takes very little resources.

Any advice on what else to check or test would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: next on my list of things to try is connecting to the router using cables. I don't know why it just occurred to me, but it could be an issue with one of our computers' wireless adapters. Hers is built into the laptop, mine is a Linksys USB adapter.

Update: I've completely ruled out the wireless connection and the issue persists. I disabled both wireless adapters, plugging into the router using cables. I'm almost certain it's my wife's computer, probably the RAM. Next step is to try replacing that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things wrong here.

1. Don't use WiFi.
2. Buy a small gigabit switch and network cables between both your computers and the switch, with another network cable to the router. You could take cables directly from your computers to the router, but I have no idea of the layout.
3. Check the firmware level on your Linksys router and upgrade. Linksys have not made a decent router in years and are now owned by Belkin, who have not made anything decent for as long as I can remember! Their support is non-existent, sadly. If you really want something decent that won't let you down **but** has a very steep learning curve regarding NAT/QOS etc, you can't beat a Mikrotik RB2011uiAS.
4. Try SSD upgrade for your wife's computer and upgrade the RAM to at least 8GB, or 16 or whatever the board can take.

All of the above will definitely improve every problem you are having - and primarily don't use WiFi.

Comment: I did put an SSD in her computer, and checked but no firmware available for the router unfortunately.

Comment: Try the cabled method and see if there is an improvement - If you get dropouts of any kind using ethernet cables then the router is at fault - If no firmware upgrade available then replace.

Comment: Also, make sure that the router has been setup for the game you are playing - normally there are some firewall rules you need to add as most online games need 2 or 3 ports to be open specifically for their server.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions, thanks. It'll take some time to report back though since the problem is intermittent and doesn't occur every time we play.